# Timezone in the future

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm working on an app that can book services in later dates in many timezones.
My problem is that when i'm getting timezone for one country, i got this timezone for now.

But this week-end we will change our timezone, and Paris (Actually +1) we'll become +2.

How can I get this timezone for a date like tuesday programmatically ?

Comment: Use [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to create the dates, it knows al about daylight saving time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various methods. 
One would be to use

```
- (NSInteger)secondsFromGMTForDate:(NSDate *)aDate
```

of `NSTimeZone` and get the GMT offset for a certain date and a certain timezone. 
Or you can use

```
– daylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate:
```

to check wether there needs a DST offset to be accounted for.